# Nuxt3 : Watch doesn't detect response changement with useLazyFetch

Tags: vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I use Nuxt3 and I would like use [$fetch](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/data-fetching#uselazyfetch)

I have a Vue component

```js
<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import {getQuestions} from "@/server/api/questions";
import {watch} from "vue";

let {data: d, error: e} = getQuestions();

watch(d , n => {
  console.log("data", n)
})
watch(e , n => {
  console.log("error", n)
})
</script>
```

My `questions` module :

```js
import {questions} from "@/api";

export let getQuestions = () => {
    const config = useRuntimeConfig()

    const { pending, data, error} = useLazyFetch(`${config.public.apiBase}${questions}`);

    return {pending, data, error};
}
```

But all `console.log` doesn't display anything. Any idea ?

---

UPDATE

My request works when HMR run, but if i reload my page, request doesn't work. Maybe framework bug ?

Comment: Some `async/await` may be missing. Also, is the `getQuestions` working? Please double check by trying out a quick `console.log` inside of it.

Comment: Yes, getQuestions works. `async/await` is missing because I want that this script not block navigation, lazy is used for that

Comment: Did you find a solution for that in the meantime?